# Use if in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use this query, but it does not work:

```
create FUNCTION getUserCreditPayment
(
    @resellerCode int,
    @userCode int,
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(
    WITH Directories AS 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN (@userCode != 0)  
            THEN 
                (SELECT * 
                 FROM UserCredit 
                 WHERE userCode = @userCode 
                   AND date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT code, date, price* - 1, 
                       userCode, userCodeDes, customerUserName, type 
                FROM UserPayment 
                WHERE userCode = @userCode 
                  AND date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate)
            ELSE
                (SELECT * 
                 FROM UserCredit 
                 WHERE userCode = @userCode 
                   AND date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT code, date, price* -1,
                       userCode, userCodeDes, customerUserName, type 
                FROM UserPayment 
                WHERE date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate)
         END
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM Directories
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check mutiple conditions and insert ,you should go for Multi table valued function..Here is one example

```
create FUNCTION getUserCreditPayment
(
   @id int
)
RETURNS --this is the table which you will return,Populate it with same schema
@test table 
(
id int,
name varchar(max)
)
as
Begin
if (@userCode != 0)
begin
insert into @test
SELECT  * FROM UserCredit where userCode=@userCode and date>=@startDate and date<@endDate
            UNION ALL SELECT code,date,price*-1,userCode,userCodeDes,customerUserName,type from UserPayment 
            where userCode=@userCode and date>=@startDate and date<@endDate
end
else 
insert into @test
SELECT  * FROM UserCredit where userCode=@userCode and date>=@startDate and date<@endDate
            UNION ALL SELECT code,date,price*-1,userCode,userCodeDes,customerUserName,type from UserPayment 
            where userCode=@userCode and date>=@startDate and date<@endD

Return
end
```

Comment: This answer uses the "old" syntax with BEGIN and END and will therefore perform very badly... There are very rare situations where you cannot reach the same with the "new" inlineable (ad-hoc) syntax, which performs much better!

Comment: Thank you for the tip,updated,could you share some examples as well

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was not clear enough. I meant the "single-statement-TVF", which is much better performing as the "multi-statement-function". Look at Naveen Kumars answer. There's just `RETURNS TABLE AS ...` and then follows a "naked" query. No `INSERT` no `@variable` no `IF-ELSE` ...

Answer (score 2):

No Need of Case and if Statement, The only Difference in both script is usercode check which can be handled using OR condition

Try With This

```
create FUNCTION getUserCreditPayment
(
    @resellerCode int,
    @userCode int,
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(
    WITH Directories AS 
    (

         SELECT  * FROM UserCredit where userCode=@userCode and date>=@startDate and date<@endDate
            UNION ALL SELECT code,date,price*-1,userCode,userCodeDes,customerUserName,type from UserPayment 
            where (userCode=@userCode OR @userCode = 0)  and date>=@startDate and date<@endDate


    )
    SELECT  * FROM   Directories
)
```

Comment: Upvote from my side, especially because you are using the *inline* TVF-syntax (without BEGIN and END)